# Counting the number of DIVs placed into a DIV via drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have had a look about the site and found some code and tried it out but its not working in any shape or form.

I am wanting to count the number of DIVs that's placed into another DIV by the user dragging and dropping but only to count the 'correct' ones then if all the correct ones are in the DIV display an alert saying well done then rest the 'game'. Also need to show how many more is needed to go to 'win'.

This is what I have so far:

JS:

```
    $('.drop').each(function(){ 
        var n = $(this).children('.draggable').length;
        $(".count").text("There are " + n + " divs inside parent box detail.");
        if(n == 2){
        alert("You got them all right! :)");
        }
        });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="foods">
              <div class="draggable" id="draggable"><img src="images/fish.png" id="draggable"></div>

              <div class="draggable" id="draggable"><img src="images/stone.png"></div>

              <div class="wrong"><img src="images/tree.png"></div>
            </div>

<div class="foods">                
<div id="droppable" class="drop">
<p>Drop here</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="foods">
        <span class="count"></span> 
</div>
```

JS Fiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/JRLZK/

Comment: Clean up your code. The ID tag should be unique. You have even defined it twice in the same element. Please try to make a jsfiddle.net out of it to let people test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it with your logic.

```
 $(function() {
    var n = 0;
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".wrong" ).draggable();

    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({    
        drop: function( event, ui) {
            console.log($(ui));
            if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("draggable")){
            $( this )
                .find( "p" )
                 .html( "Correct! :)" );
                n++;
        $(".count").text("There are " + n + " divs inside parent box detail.");
        if(n == 2){
        alert("You got them all right! :)");
        }

            } else {
                    $( this )
                    .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Wrong! :(" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks thats it. I feel rather silly now as it was really simple!

Comment: Oh well, sometimes it just takes someone else to look at it.  jQuery is fun though isn't it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the duplicate IDs you are giving. I used class instead of id, but you can apply your own logic there.

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({    
    drop: function( event, ui) {
        if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("draggable")){
        $( this )
            .find( "p" )
                .html( "Correct! :)" );
        } else {
                $( this )
                .find( "p" )
                .html( "Wrong! :(" );
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRLZK/1/)

---

**Update**

Here is a workaround for the count

```
var div = $("<div />"); //a temp container
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({    
    drop: function( event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.clone().appendTo(div);
        if(div.children(".draggable").length == 2) {
            alert('correct');
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRLZK/2/)

Comment: The drag and drop works how I am wanting it but its this counting part thats not.